# Lawn mower robot (type of cutter)

Tags: motor, mechanism

If not all, but major types of lawn mower robots are rotary mowers.
I presume<sup>1</sup> that reel mower is more efficient, and is said to leave a better lawn health and cut. So, why industry go to the other option?

---

<sup>1 - I'm assuming the efficiency, as electrical rotary mowers have at least 900W universal-motors or induction motors, and a manual reel mower is capable nearly the same cutting speed.</sup>

Comment: These guys: http://www.husqvarna.com/za/products/robotic-mowers/automower-solar-hybrid/ use something like exacto blades for cutting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotary mowers are mechanically simpler, so cheaper to make. The rotary mower is more tolerant of getting dull, and if you run over something like small trees or rocks, the blades take less damage, and the motor is harder to jam and stall.
The blades are also easier to sharpen.
For this simplicity, you get a poorer cut, and more grass damage.
I do agree, though, that the reel mower would be more efficient. You'd probably need more sensors though, to watch for jamming.